# Unable to run teamcity gradle build on my local windows agent :

Tags: selenium, gradle, teamcity

I have setup a gradle build in teamcity server with agent on my local windows machine .When I try to run the build through team city my build gets cancelled with the below logs  :

.....

Clearing temporary directory (path of the directory)

Build cancelled

Let me know if more details are needed .

Comment: Make your question clear.

Comment: Why is selenium tagged?